# Why is GridView.builder creating the same random image?

Tags: flutter

How is it that "http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" returns the same image for all the grid tiles in the following example?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: 100,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(child: Image.network("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/")),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

It seems that the result of the first request to "http://lorempixel.com/300/300" is used for all images. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the structure of `Image` widget and its `Image.network` constructor which caches all `Images` loaded through it. They mention that in the [Image widget documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) :

> All network images are cached regardless of HTTP headers.